# URL Rewrite: multiple addresses per article

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla, seo

I have a Joomla! website with rewrite rules activated. My article URl is mysite.com/category/ID-alias.html. The only thing which is important (from this url) is the id, because when I can access the article with any text at "category" and any text at "alias".

Let's show a concrete example:

```
My article URL: mysite.com/flowers/15-begonia.html
```

I can access the same by changing category name and alias directly from url:

```
mysite.com/tralala/15-anything.html //Shows the same article as above.
```

Is this SEO? If one of my visitors want to destroy my website SEO, can he open my articles with different addresses (like above) and Google will say that articles are duplicated? Does Google knows when a visitor goes to a webpage to which link doesn't exists anywhere?

Hope my question is clear.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google do a good job of deciding which is the "right" version of a page - it is worth watching this video to see how they handle this situation:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mQZY7EmjbMA

Since these wrong URLs should not be linked to from anywhere, it is unlikely they will be indexed by mistake.

However, should they index the wrong version of a page, setting a sitemap with the right one will usually fix it.

A visitor could not harm your SEO with this knowledge.  The worst they could do would be to provide good links to a non-indexed page, which would cause the wrong URL to be indexed.  However, it would then be very easy for you to 301 redirect that page and turn their attempts at harm into an SEO benefit.

I personally think Joomla should look into adding the canonical tag, but if you want that currently, you must use an extension like this:

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/seo-a-metadata/url-canonicalization-/25795

(NB I have never used this extension so cannot guarantee its quality - the reviews are good, though)